# Is there an example of Highcharts Gantt that works with Highcharts 6.0.4?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to integrate the Gantt example available at https://jsfiddle.net/t0r8qz9p/255/ with Highcharts 6.0.4.  When the highcharts-gantt.src.js file is loaded the following console error is generated:

```
Error: Highcharts error #16: www.highcharts.com/errors/16
```

which corresponded with "Highcharts already defined in the page", and the Highcharts.ganttChart widget is not loaded.

Is there a version of this example compatible with 6.0.4?  Or what changes are necessary for this to work.

Comment: Looks like highcharts-gantt.src.js ist loading both components. Have you already test to just load gantt.src.js next to your highstock as done in this example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ztu38vw0/) ?

Comment: Thanks - that was it.  I just commented out the code relating to the loading of Highcharts and it looks to be working OK.